# The parameter lost value after a loop

Tags: c++

```
void genomicStatistic(int numberOfRow, int numberOfColumn, char arr[7][8]) {
int P[4][100];
char C[100];
int max = 0;
// 0. Set the initial value 

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumn; j++) {
        P[i][j] = 0;
        cout << numberOfRow << endl;
        cout << numberOfColumn << endl;
    }
}}


void main() {
char arr[7][8]{
    {'A' ,'T' ,'C' ,'C', 'A',' G', 'C', 'T'},
    {'A' ,'T' ,'C' ,'C', 'A',' G', 'C', 'T'},
    {'A' ,'T' ,'C' ,'C', 'A',' G', 'C', 'T'},
    {'A' ,'T' ,'C' ,'C', 'A',' G', 'C', 'T'},
    {'A' ,'T' ,'C' ,'C', 'A',' G', 'C', 'T'},
    {'A' ,'T' ,'C' ,'C', 'A',' G', 'C', 'T'},
    {'A' ,'T' ,'C' ,'C', 'A',' G', 'C', 'T'},

};
genomicStatistic(7, 8, arr);   }
```

At // 0. , I try to set the initial value for array but after complier finish loop, numberOfRow and numberOfColumn is 0. I couldn't make sense why it happen, please help.

Comment: Sounds like some buffer overrun somewhere, or some post-usage variable optimization since the variables are never used again after the loop. Try using `cout <<` *after* the loop for these variables.

Comment: The dimensions of `P` are not the same as your loop bounds. You’re writing far outside it.

Comment: `P[i][j] = 0;` might be `arr[i][j] = 0;` maybe?

Comment: I suspect a case of ”first, I will declare all the variables I might need...”, followed by a typo. Declaring late protects against bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int P[4][100];` is defined for values from `0..3` for the first index. You use values from `0..6`.  `P` and `C` are superfluous anyway.

By the way you are not really using C++. This is a more C++ way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void genomicStatistic(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> &arr) {   
    for (const auto &row : arr) {
        for (const auto item : row) {
            std::cout << item << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> arr{
        {"A", "T", "C", "C", "A", " G", "C", "T"}, 
        {"A", "T", "C", "C", "A", " G", "C", "T"},
        {"A", "T", "C", "C", "A", " G", "C", "T"},
        {"A", "T", "C", "C", "A", " G", "C", "T"},
        {"A", "T", "C", "C", "A", " G", "C", "T"},
        {"A", "T", "C", "C", "A", " G", "C", "T"},
        {"A", "T", "C", "C", "A", " G", "C", "T"},

    };
    genomicStatistic(arr);
}
```

Comment: Why the switch to `std::string` though?

Comment: The entry G also contains a space.

Comment: Not sure that's intended, but well spotted.

Comment: If it is not intended, the std::string can be replaced by a char.

Answer (score 0):

Because you work with a copy, when you finish your function this copy will delete (C and C++ in parameter use copy to pass values don't like java or others languages use reference ) and you should use reference or pointer in your parameter.